# hook_menu implementation page not found error drupal 7.10

Tags: routes

I am trying to figure out why hook_menu implementation is not working anymore after upgrade from 7.4 to 7.10 for a custom module
Menu links were working properly until update to latest version. after update all custom module links are deleted from table menu_links and menu_router.

ex. of one of the menu link:

```
$items = array(); 

$items['a/main'] = array(
'page callback' => 'main',
'description' => 'Main front page',
'access callback' => TRUE,
);

return $items;
```

This code was working properly in 7.4 but not anymore.
Have tried to do all cache clearing, menu_rebuild()... etc. nothing seems to work.

Even tried to copy sample code from hook_menu API page like
    function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
    );
    return $items;
    }

```
function mymodule_abc_view($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {
// ...
}
```

and does not work as well.

So I am wondering if anything changed after 7.4 version or I am really missing obvious details?

Thank you for comments.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a 'title' to your return array.

I noticed that the D7 menu [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) lists 'Title' as required:

```
"title": Required. The untranslated title of the menu item.
```

Now there is a [comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7#comment-13099) on the doc page that claims it is not required.

But That comment is from March 20, 2011.

Perhaps the title is now finally required in a more recent release.

Edit:
Your code from comment:

```
/** * Implementation menu(). / */
function misite_menu() {
    $items = array(); 
    $items['a/main'] = array( 
             'title' => 'main',
             'page callback' => 'main', 
             'description' => t('Main front page'),
             'access callback' => TRUE, ); 
    return $items; 
} 

/* * Implementation hook_theme(). */ 
function misite_theme() { 
    return array( 'main' => array ( 
        'template' => 'main', 
        'variables' => array('title' => NULL), 
        ),
    ); 
}

function main() {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'a'); 
    $title = t(''); 
    $build['mainelement'] = array( '#theme' => 'main', 
                                                '#title' => $title, ); 
    $output = drupal_render($build); 
    return $output; 
}
```

Several observations.
1) I think your inclusion of hook_theme could be causing needless grief. Try getting an example of hook_menu working independent of hook_theme.

2) I wouldn't use 'main' as a page callback name; it may not be conflicting with another function elsewhere but I don't think it is a good idea regardless.

Try this:

```
function misite_menu() {
    $items = array(); 
    $items['a/my_main'] = array( 
             'title' => 'my_main',
             'page callback' => 'my_main', 
             'description' => t('Main front page'),
             'access callback' => TRUE
            ); 
    return $items; 
} 

function my_main() { 
    $output = 'HERE I AM'; 
    print($output); 
}
```

Then navigate to a/my_main and see if you can see "HERE I AM". If you can then you know your hook menu is working and that your problem is in your hook_theme.